# Does a square matrix always commute with its transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does a square matrix always commute with its transpose? which means If M is a square matrix, then $M^TM=MM^T$? I just couldn't give a counterexample.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix

Comment: HINT: Test with some non-diagonalizable matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Counterexample:
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
More generally, an upper triangular matrix will commute with its transpose if and only if it is diagonal.  If $M$ commutes with its transpose, it is called a "normal" matrix.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple counter example: Let 
$
M = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right),
$
then $M M^T = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$
and $M^T M = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$.

A real matrix $M$ which satisfies $M^T M = M M^T$ is called [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix). 
A general version of the Spectral Theorem states that $M$ is normal if and only
if there is a diagonal matrix $D$ and a unitary matrix $P$ such that 
$M = P D P^{-1}$. (Here $D$ and $P$ may be complex.)

Comment: This version of the spectral theorem requires that we allow $P$ and $D$ to be complex, and that $P$ is unitary as a complex matrix.

Comment: Corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. Here is a counter example (python code):

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[1,2,3],[1.1,0.1,0.2],[1,1,100]])
np.dot(m,m.T)[0,0]
np.dot(m.T,m)[0,0]
```

The first entry is 14 and the second is 3.21/